# How to route the user to a new page with angularjs and firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

For example: during the registration I choose the username "MyUserName", then, when I confirm my data the web-app directs to a new sub-page using the username (the URL would be: `nameofmywebapp.com/MyUserName`) just like instagram does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely certain what you are asking, but I think you might be asking how to route the user to a new page once they are logged in? this tutorial has a section called, "Authenticating Users Using AngularFire" that shows how to do just that: https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial#authenticating-users-using-angularfire. They do this by routing the user to a new page based on the user's "state".

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl as authCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'auth/login.html'
})
.state('register', {
  url: '/register',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl as authCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'auth/register.html'
})
```